# angularJS + UI bootstrap typeahead: filter:$viewValue doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead

I don't manage to get the filter:$viewValue work in an input with typeahead.
I get the whole list displayed with the entered characters highlighted.
I expect a filtered list depending on the characters entered.

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/X3C0fP52ZTi55LJtXfnu?p=preview

In my real project, I need to apply two filters as below.

```
<input autocomplete="off" 
  type="text" 
  placeholder="Selected Criteria"     
  ng-model="MgtCtrl.editActionData.selectedCriteria" 
  typeahead='criteria as criteria.name for criteria in MgtCtrl.criteriaList | criteriaByApplication:MgtCtrl.getTriggerApplication() | filter:$viewValue | orderBy:"name"'>
```

Comment: There are currently a few open tickets regarding the typeahead with Angular 1.3. You might want to check their board: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/milestones/0.13.0

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your collection item is an object, then you need to specify which property the filter should take into account.

As per your example, the filter would look like this:

```
| filter:{'name':$viewValue}
```

Since you're displaying the name property, it may be the name you want to filter by, but I may be wrong. So you need to adequate it with your context.

References:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter